# R text mining documents from multiple txt files

Tags: r, text, data-mining

I have multiple txt files, each referring to a different month of the year (for many years). So, how I could analyze these files (text mining) each of these separately from a unique corpus (or something similar), by taking track of the month-year reference, thank you.

Comment: Take the filename and create a dataframe/list/... with the results of the analysis where i.e. the colnames correspond to the filename.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example I programmed for Game of Thrones subtitles. The subtitles are in the form 60 text files, one file for one episode in the form of S01E01 were we wanted to keep the episode information.

The following code will read the files into a list, and will turn it into a dataframe with episode information and text. You will have to adapt it to your own problem.

```
library(plyr)
####### Read data ######

filenames <- list.files("Set7/Game of Thrones Subtitles", pattern="*", full.names=TRUE)
filenames_short <- list.files("Set7/Game of Thrones Subtitles", pattern="*", full.names=FALSE)

ldf <- alply(.data=filenames,.margins=1,.fun=scan,what = "character", quiet = T, quote = "")
names(ldf) <- filenames_short


# Loop over all filenames
# Turns list into two columns of a dataframe, episode and word
# create empty dataframe    
df_got_subs <- as.data.frame(NULL)


    for (i in 1:60) {

      # extract listname
      # vector with list name
      listenname <- filenames_short[i]
      vec_listenname <- rep.int(listenname,length(ldf[[i]]))

      # Doublecheck
      cat("listenname: ",listenname,"\n")

      # turn list element into vector
      vec_subs <- as.vector(ldf[[i]])

      # create dataframe from vectors
      df_subs <- cbind.data.frame(vec_listenname,vec_subs,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

      # attach to the "big" dataframe
      df_got_subs <- rbind.data.frame(df_got_subs,df_subs)

    }

    # test datastructure
    str(df_got_subs)

    # change column names
    colnames(df_got_subs) <- c("episode","subs")
```

The whole text mining we did with the tidytext package from Julia Silge. I didn't post the code because she gives much better examples in this post:
http://juliasilge.com/blog/Life-Changing-Magic/

I hope this helps with your problem.